# Counter - skipping element and not increasing during the for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, counter, linear-search

So I'm coding a basic login system for my class, and I'm using a for loop and counter to linear search a list. However when I input a username that should be correct it returns as unauthorized. I've tried printing the counter between each pass of the loop and I've found even though the range is (0,6) it only counts up to three?

[image of code, shell and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04zuO.png)

```
import random

userver = 0
userList = ["Arabella12", "Constance01", "Hugo11", "James09", "Jane12", "Max06", "Ted04"]
pwrdList = ["bella12", "1234", "HGWel!", "j@me£S", "Password", "notpassword", "ted4"]
found = False
pfound = False

def login():
    username = input("Type in your username ")
    index1 = 0
    wrong = 0
    found = False
    c3 = 0
    print("index one before c3 loop=", index1)  #delete after testing
    for c3 in range(0, 6): #username check counter
        if username == userList[c3]:  #if username is found with the counter c3
            found = True  #making the key for the next part of the code true
            index = s(c3)
            print(index," is the index")
            c3 = c3 + 1
            break
        elif found == False:
            print("c3: ", c3)  #checking counter- delete after debugging
            print("unauthorised user...attempting again")  #if username isnt present
            c3 = c3 + 1  #upping the counter
            exit

login()
```

Comment: Why are you "upping the counter", rather than just letting the `for` loop progress on its own? Perhaps you need to [read more about `for` loops in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: What is point of using `exit` inside for loop?

Comment: You are interfering with the counter - do not increment it "manually".

Answer (score 1):

Range is not correct, because you use `“` instead of `"`. Also you do not need to use exit in elif and increment the counter- it's done automatically